# WP7: how to add a control to ListBox from C# code

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way to add a control (for example, a button) to ListBox for each items in WP7 using C# code? And when click the button, it will go to the detailed page of the selected item.

Comment: Are you handling SelectionChanged? If you're new to WP7/ C# in general, this is likely what you're looking for.

Comment: willmel, not SelectionChanged, I just want to know how to add a control to ListBox when binding data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox` to add a custom template for the items. It could look like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourDataSource}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding ItemName}" Command="{Binding ItemCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: MatthiasG, this is the code in XAML, I want to know how to add a control to ListBox when binding data in C#.

Comment: @AndyWan My XAML code shows how you would define a custom template for every item which is bound to the ListBox. You're looking for another behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the XAML string and then load it to the XAML page using the XamlReader.Load .

XamlReader.Load("XAML string")...